# Building tree type structure of a network

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a GIS specialist working on optic fiber infrastructure

Newbie in SQL (Microsoft SQL Server) I'm currently trying to build a tree like structure of our network from root to customer

I have already built a very repetitive query that consists of one root query, to which I join the same query over and over until I reach the end of the network.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM  
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            B.bay,
            B.drawer,
            B.connector,
            C.cable_code,
            F.tube,
            F.fiber,
            F.route_id,
            C.cable_origin,
            C.cable_destination
        FROM cable_table C
            INNER JOIN fiber_table F ON F.cable_code = C.cable_code
            INNER JOIN bay_table B ON B.cable_code = C.cable_code
        WHERE B.tubeid = F.tubeid
        AND   B.fiberid = F.fiberid
    ) root

    LEFT JOIN 
    
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
              C.cable_code cable_code1,
              F.tube tube1,
              F.fiber fiber1,
              F.route_id route_id1,
              C.cable_origin cable_origin1,
              C.cable_destination cable_destination1

        FROM cable_table C
            INNER JOIN fiber_table F ON F.cable_code = C.cable_code
    ) cable1
    
    ON  root.route_id = cable1.route_id1
    AND root.cable_destination = cable1.cable_origin1
    
ORDER BY root.bay, root.drawer, root.connector, root.cable_code, root.tube, root.fiber

--From there I join the new query to the last, using the same column name, only changing the last number by 2, 3, 4 ...
```

Rules : Connectors, tubes, fibers are not always lined up like fiber 1 from tube 1 on connector 1. It can be mixed up. Fiber 12 on tube 22 connector 79

Here is an example of the expected result :

```
+------------------+--------------------------+-------------+--------------------+------+-------+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|       bay        |          drawer          |  connector  |     cable_code     | tube | fiber | route_id |   cable_origin   | cable_destination  |    cable_code1     | tube1 | fiber1 | route_id1 |   cable_origin1    | cable_destination1 |
+------------------+--------------------------+-------------+--------------------+------+-------+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+
| PMU-25-003-EG-01 | TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A | CO000000001 | CDI-25-003-EG-A005 |    1 |     1 |   404979 | PMU-25-003-EG-01 | PBO-25-003-EG-A005 | CDI-25-003-EG-A010 |     1 |      1 |    404979 | PBO-25-003-EG-A005 | PEC-25-003-EG-A010 |
| PMU-25-003-EG-01 | TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A | CO000000002 | CDI-25-003-EG-A005 |    1 |     2 |   951378 | PMU-25-003-EG-01 | PBO-25-003-EG-A005 | CDI-25-003-EG-A010 |     1 |      2 |    951378 | PBO-25-003-EG-A005 | PEC-25-003-EG-A010 |
| PMU-25-003-EG-01 | TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A | CO000000003 | CDI-25-003-EG-A005 |    1 |     3 |   404981 | PMU-25-003-EG-01 | PBO-25-003-EG-A005 | CDI-25-003-EG-A010 |     1 |      3 |    404981 | PBO-25-003-EG-A005 | PEC-25-003-EG-A010 |
+------------------+--------------------------+-------------+--------------------+------+-------+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The tree can have up to 20 nodes so my query consists of the root and x20 cable query. It's very repetitive and I doubt it's very efficient SQL wise.  That's why i'm here, I now it's the a 'I am missing the trick moment' and I need your help to build a better (Recursive ?) query that can prevent having 20 times the same block and possibly speed up process time.
Here a script with some sample of my different tables

```
CREATE TABLE cable_table 
(
    [cable_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [cable_origin] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [cable_destination] [varchar](255) NULL
)
INSERT INTO cable_table
VALUES
('CDI-25-003-EG-A005','PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'PBO-25-003-EG-A005'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B005','PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'PBO-25-003-EG-B005'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C005','PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'PBO-25-003-EG-C005'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A010','PBO-25-003-EG-A005', 'PBO-25-003-EG-A010'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B010','PBO-25-003-EG-B005', 'PBO-25-003-EG-B010'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C010','PBO-25-003-EG-C005', 'PBO-25-003-EG-C010'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A015','PBO-25-003-EG-A010', 'PBO-25-003-EG-A015'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B015','PBO-25-003-EG-B010', 'PBO-25-003-EG-B015'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C015','PBO-25-003-EG-C010', 'PBO-25-003-EG-C015')

CREATE TABLE fiber_table
(
    [cable_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [route_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [tubeid] [bigint] NULL,
    [tube] [int] NULL,
    [fiberid] [bigint] NULL,
    [fiber] [int] NULL
  
)
INSERT INTO fiber_table
VALUES

('CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '484979', '1800', '1', '187371', '1'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '959378', '1800', '1', '187372', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '472981', '1800', '1', '187373', '3'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '752894', '1800', '1', '187374', '4'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '457883', '1800', '1', '187381', '1'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '457236', '1800', '1', '187382', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '997855', '1800', '1', '187383', '3'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '374564', '1800', '1', '187384', '4'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '455883', '1800', '1', '187391', '1'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '785696', '1800', '1', '187392', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '453453', '1800', '1', '187393', '3'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '777784', '1800', '1', '187394', '4'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A010', '484979', '1800', '1', '187541', '1'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A010', '959378', '1800', '1', '187542', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A010', '472981', '1800', '1', '187543', '3'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A010', '752894', '1800', '1', '187544', '4'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B010', '457883', '1800', '1', '187641', '1'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B010', '457236', '1800', '1', '187642', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B010', '997855', '1800', '1', '187643', '3'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C010', '785696', '1800', '1', '189642', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A015', '484979', '1800', '1', '189881', '1'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A015', '959378', '1800', '1', '189882', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A015', '472981', '1800', '1', '189883', '3'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-A015', '752894', '1800', '1', '189884', '4'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B015', '457883', '1800', '1', '188771', '1'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B015', '457236', '1800', '1', '188772', '2'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-B015', '997855', '1800', '1', '188773', '3'),
('CDI-25-003-EG-C015', '785696', '1800', '1', '188772', '2')

CREATE TABLE bay_table
(
    [bay] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [drawer] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [connector] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [cable_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [tubeid] [bigint] NULL,
    [fiberid] [bigint] NULL,
)
  
INSERT INTO bay_table
VALUES

    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000001', 'CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '1800', '187371'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000002', 'CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '1800', '187372'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000003', 'CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '1800', '187373'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000004', 'CDI-25-003-EG-A005', '1800', '187374'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000005', 'CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '1800', '187381'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000006', 'CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '1800', '187382'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000007', 'CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '1800', '187383'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000008', 'CDI-25-003-EG-B005', '1800', '187384'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000009', 'CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '1800', '187391'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000010', 'CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '1800', '187392'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000011', 'CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '1800', '187393'),
    ('PMU-25-003-EG-01', 'TIR-25-003-EG-01-A2-01-A', 'CO000000012', 'CDI-25-003-EG-C005', '1800', '187394')
```

Comment: I would try to use a dynamic query (Transact-SQL) where column names are in variables and build is in a for loop (or a recursive function)

Comment: Although not impossible, this is not something you _want_ to solve in SQL; this is a job for the application layer (business logic).

Comment: I think you might be looking for a recursive cte.